# while文のブロックが一度も実行されない

Tags: python

ブロックが一度も実行されないのを直したいのですがどこが見違っているのでしょうか？
コード

```
print('プログラムを開始します')

n = 10
while n < 0: # nが0よりも大きい間、以下の処理を繰り返す
    print(n)
    n = n - 1

print('プログラムを終了します')
```

実行結果が期待と違います
実際 ================================
プログラムを開始します
プログラムを終了します
期待 ================================
プログラムを開始します
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
プログラムを終了します

Comment: whileはループを終了する条件ではなく、ループを実行する条件を書きます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ブロックが一度も実行されないように直したい

これが期待なら

> 実際 ================================
> プログラムを開始します
> プログラムを終了します

この実際の結果は期待どおりなのではないでしょうか。

> 期待 ================================
> プログラムを開始します
> 10
> 9
> 8
> 7
> 6
> 5
> 4
> 3
> 2
> 1
> プログラムを終了します

この結果を期待するのなら

```
while n < 0: # nが0よりも大きい間、以下の処理を繰り返す
```

条件式が誤っています。コメントどおりの条件なら

```
while n > 0: # nが0よりも大きい間、以下の処理を繰り返す
```

要するに不等号の向きが逆です。